# Qual é a diferença entre void main() e main() em Dart?

Tags: dart

A pouco tempo comecei a estudar Dart, e vendo alguns tutoriais na internet percebi que existem pessoas que usam o `main() {}` e outras que usam o `void main() {}`, como por exemplo:

com `void`:

```
void main() {
  print("Olá, Mundo!");
}
```

sem `void`:

```
main() {
  print("Olá, Mundo!");
}
```

Executando o programa em ambos os exemplos eu obtenho o mesmo resultado, alguém pode me explicar qual a diferença entre usar e não usar o `void`?

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Basicamente pq `void` traduzido é **(vazio)**, como o método **`main()`** não possui retorno por padrão e dart é fortemente tipado, alguns utilizam para deixar explícito que o retorno é vazio, ainda mais se for em um tutorial.

Comment: A diferença entre ambas é apenas semântica, para o compilado ambas terão o retorno do tipo "void".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Void é quando uma função não retorna valor algum.

Quando o tipo não é declarado, o Dart tenta inferir seu valor.
Assim, o Dart infere que a função:

```
main()
```

Relacionar o item

equivale a

```
void main()
```

Muitas linguagens de programação usam o retorno da função main para retornar um exitcode. Não é caso do Dart. Como ele também pode rodar no browser (se compilado para JS), não faz sentido ele ter exitcode, assim decidiram definir que main() sempre retorna void mesmo que declarado diferentemente.

Assim, você até pode declarar sua função main() como:

```
int main()
```

mas mesmo que você finalize essa função com `return 1;` ainda assim ela não retornará valor algum, pois o compilador vai assumir sempre que ela retorna void. (Porém existem propostas para mudar esse comportamento).